# MySQL: Create stored procedures dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a database to which several real users have access using JDBC. The separation of these users is very crucial, such that they are neither able see nor manipulate each other's data.

To separate the users' data, I decided to create the few corresponding tables for every user, and only give the owning user the permissions on this table. This is all done automatically in a stored procedure.

Besides this table separation, I want a user only to execute stored procedures to work with his tables, not arbitrary SQL queries.

Let's consider an example procedure like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(IN p_identifier VARCHAR(30), IN p_key INT(10))
BEGIN
SET @p_identifier = p_identifier;
SET @p_key = p_key;

SET @s = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', p_identifier, '_mytable WHERE key =?;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt USING @p_key,
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it like `CALL MyProcedure('ad3e981b', 2);`.

So far, so good.

Problems arise since this procedure is used by all users (the first paraeter is the table-prefix). This is bad, because once a user gets execution privileges for `MyProcedure`, he is able to to provide any table-prefix at will and mess with other user's data - so my user separation is gone. This is the problem I need to solve.

I currently see two solutions:

- **Don’t use stored procedures:** Just give INSERT/DELETE/SELECT privileges on the user's table only to the user. This is simple and works - but I'd prefer to only call stored procedures over JDBC, not arbitrary SQL queries.
- **Make a stored procedure for EVERY user**, in which the table prefix is invariant (e.g, `table-prefix_MyProcedure()`, which is only executable by one user). Then, assign the execution privilege only to the corresponding user. However, this should be done automatically on request - hence, I need to be able to create a stored procedure with a parameterized name to set this up (phew). As the title suggests, this is the way I want to go - but I really struggle with the syntax of dynamically creating a stored procedure (in a stored procedure) and thus, I'm really not sure if this is how I should proceed.

Any ideas how I got approach this problem?

Regards,

raute

Comment: Check the `SQL SECURITY` option in the definition of stored procedures [13.1.15 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html), I think you can achieve what you need with that option.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Adding the parameter "SQL SECURITY INVOKER" and granting the user the "delete" privilege on the corresponding table did the trick. Thank you very much!